# How do I know which agent is released from the Delay block?

Tags: java, modeling, anylogic

I have a this model in AnyLogic 7. How can I know which agent is released from "delayBA" unit using the code in the "function" function that is called when you exit the "delayBA" block?

[image: My model]

Answer (score 2):

Try `agent.getIndex()` in the onRelease code box.

Also refer to why it is "agent" here: [the magic light bulb](http://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling)